# Bundle custom files in ClickOnce installer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, zip, installation, clickonce, publish

I tried to bundle a .zip file into ClickOnce installer and I set `Build Action` to `Content` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Always`, but still I can't see and select the .zip file in **Application Files** in publish settings.

Comment: The act of setting the file to Content should make it appear in the `Publish > Application Files` list. Have you tried removing and re-adding it to the project, and also checking that your project file is read/write so VS can update it? 

If this doesn't work you could try adding the file information to the project file manually by editing your .csproj or .vbproj file outside of Visual Studio. 

This [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mwade/2008/06/29/how-to-publish-files-which-are-not-in-the-project/](MSDN post)  shows the expected content of the <PublishFile> itemgroup you could add.